# Processing Database table from Beginning of Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, data-warehouse

Question: This might be a beginner developer questions but need some clarifications. What is best / mostly used / best practice to process data into database table from beginning of time (for example data from January 1900) ? Do people pull and process data from beginning of time and process it at once? Do people pull data based on window of time (example processing by one Month of Year at a time or one Year a time). Also when there is modification of data in June 2000, do people reprocess it from beginning of time or just reprocess for June 2000. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here.  Both approaches are common, and people typically do the simplest thing that performs acceptably.  Note that full reload is something you occasionally have to do anyway, so it's the simplest approach if it's practial.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, appreciated